# Subquery in from of DQL query

Tags: doctrine-orm, dql

I want to translate one of my MySQL query into a DQL one to have a better compatibility of my application.

Here is the query (kinf of) :

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT count(id) as Context FROM context__item) t0
LEFT JOIN (SELECT count(id) Progress FROM progress__family)          t1 ON 1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT count(id) Presentation FROM presentation__family)  t2 ON 1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT count(id) Discovery FROM discovery__family)        t3 ON 1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT count(id) Objection FROM objection__item)          t4 ON 1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT count(id) FROM answer__item)                       t5 ON 1
...
```

The goal of my query is to have the count of all the lines of each table in my DB into columns (that why the LEFT JOIN is done ON nothing).

I don't find any equivalent to my query or any way to handle it in DQL.

Comment: Have you considered creating a `VIEW` for it in the database, and setting up a corresponding entity for it in Doctrine? Might be simpler.

Comment: Ho yes that's a great idea, I'll try that. 
Badly, I wanted a dynamic query (I don't need to count the lines on every table all the time, sometime only 2 or 3 are needed) but if there is all in the view, I can extract the datas I need after, in the code. Thank you =)

Comment: But now that I create my `VIEW`, I can't handle it with an entity, there is nothing on the Doctrine documentation about `VIEW`. Do you know how to do it ?